# Angular ui-router, how do I cancel the following resolves, after one of them triggers an error - reject?

Tags: angularjs

I am using the ui-router in the following code and I have two resolves.

1. I check if there is an authentication token.
2. I get some data from the server.

If there is no token, I reject the resolve and redirect to user to the login page.

**The problem is, the "movieList" resolve is still happening - how can I cancel the resolve?**

Any ideas?

```
angular.module('app.code').config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('code', {
            url: '/code',
            templateUrl: 'app/sections/code/code.tpl.html',
            controller: 'CodeCtrl',
            resolve: {

                /**
                 *  Auth middleware.
                 */
                UserData: ['$q', 'Session', function ($q, Session) {
                    var userData = Session.getUserData();
                    if (userData.token) {
                        return userData;
                    }
                    return $q.reject('login');
                }],

                // IF I TRIGGER THE REJECT ABOVE, HOW DO I CANCEL THIS FOLLOWING RESOLVE?

                movieList: ['$q', 'MoviesService', function ($q, MoviesService) {

                    var deferred =  $q.defer();

                    MoviesService.query().then(
                        function (success) {
                            deferred.resolve(success.data);
                        },
                        function (error) {
                            $q.reject('home');
                        }
                    );

                    return deferred.promise;
                }]
            }
        });
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add UserData as a dependency to the movieList resolve function. Now movieList will be called only if UserData is resolved.

```
 movieList: ['$q', 'MoviesService', 'UserData', function ($q, MoviesService, UserData) {

                var deferred =  $q.defer();

                MoviesService.query().then(
                    function (success) {
                        deferred.resolve(success.data);
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        $q.reject('home');
                    }
                );

                return deferred.promise;
            }
```